# How to get the sum of textbox column in Datatable?

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

My requirement is that, when use `textbox` in datatable column , then sum of `textbox` column not working in footer total.

```
          <thead>
            <tr>          
              <th style="width: 30%">Salary Head</th>
              <th style="width: 20%">Amount</th>
              <th style="width: 20%">Type</th>
              <th style="width: 30%">Actual Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
             <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                <th></th>
             </tr>
          </tfoot>
```

```js
  $('#list_table').DataTable( {
        "searching": false,
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 3 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

             $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(total.toFixed(3));   

        }
    } );
} );
```

Datatable Normal column is working, But When use textbox column in Datatable then the sum of column is not working.

Comment: Elaborate your question in detail and also show what you've tried so far...

Comment: Wee need more explanation and your code

Answer (score 0):

Try its to calculate sum

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.column( 4 ).data().sum(); // as fees is your fourth column
```

More Info:

http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()#

https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/api.html

Otherwise refer that link :

https://codepedia.info/jquery-sum-of-textbox-values-in-table-column/

Comment: My code is working for summing normal datatable column , but when use textbox in datatable column then it is not working.

Comment: have you refer that link ? https://codepedia.info/jquery-sum-of-textbox-values-in-table-column/